# "Post.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am new to using django and I'm creating a simple webpage that takes in user input and saves it to the Model Form

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Post


class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post',)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .forms import HomeForm


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()

            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = HomeForm()
            return redirect('home.html')

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

home.html

```
{% block body %}
<div class ='container'>
    <h1>Home</h1>

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button type ='submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

When I run the server the webpage comes up normal but when I type in some input an error page pops up and says : ValueError at /

Cannot assign ">": "Post.user" must be a "User" instance.

Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you signed in? Is `request.user` an authenticated user?

Comment: I think that is the problem. Thank you

Comment: If you want anonymous users to create posts then you need to make the foreign key nullable